# How to display a reverse-ordered list in HTML?

Tags: css, html

I need help. Is there any way to show reverse ordered list in css/scss? Something similar to this:

```
  5. I am a list item.
  4. I am a list item.
  3. I am a list item.
  2. I am a list item.
  1. I am a list item.
```

Comment: Do you want the numbers to count down or do you want to reverse the order of the items? It isn't possible to tell from your example.

Comment: Whatever the solution, please be mindful of WCAG SC 1.3.2 Meaningful Sequence https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/meaningful-sequence

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could rotate the parent element `180deg` and then rotate the children elements `-180deg`.

```
ul {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul > li {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6uhdLhw/)

Alternatively, you could use flex boxes along with the [**`order` property.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

---

Although this isn't technically reversing the order, you could also use [**`counter-increment`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment) along with a psuedo element.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ny3o4jjp/)

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    counter-reset:item 6;
}
ul > li {
    counter-increment:item -1;
}
ul > li:after {
    content: counter(item);
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome "hack". Thank you. :)

Comment: I can't help but wonder what the story behind figuring that this would work is. Solved my problem of the day, thank you.

Comment: 'transform' is awesome, but it changes scroll direction as well. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Rubycon - I suppose you could add `direction: rtl` to flip the scrollbar like in this updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/p8coyed4/ That is relatively hackish though since the initial position on the scrollbar is then at the bottom...  So you may just want to utilize the flexbox model at that point and either use the `order` property or `flex-direction: column-reverse`

Comment: @JoshCrozier thx. "direction: rtl" is not exactly what I need. Actually 'transform' itself changes the scroll direction (down->up) and it becomes a different UX for end users than usual. "flex-direction: column-reverse" looks promising, but seems it has a bug for Firefox..

Comment: this is the simplest hack for this thing.

Answer (score 63):

You can use flexbox to achieve this. It allows you to reverse the order with the `flex-direction` property.

```
ol { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

li {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

- [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)
- [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9b12ep0o/)
- [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: it has less browser support.

Comment: it doesn't support IE8,9.

Comment: Nor does the transform solution.

Comment: @Quentin Nice one ;). But the counter increment one does ~ http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters

Comment: The counter increment doesn't reverse the order of the list items, it reverses the order of the numbering. The OP never clarified what they wanted.

Comment: @Quentin: I will go with counter increment not transform one.

Comment: why the `li { flex: 0}` ?

Answer (score 31):

```
<ol reversed>
  <li>I am a list item.</li>
  <li>I am a list item.</li>
  <li>I am a list item.</li>
  <li>I am a list item.</li>
  <li>I am a list item.</li>
</ol>
```

- [w3schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_reversed.asp)
- [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ol_reversed)

Comment: Provide a reference link to the ol reversed attribute.

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Comment: FYI, this reverses the numbering, not the order of the list items.

Comment: @user2864740 official link from MDN web docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#attr-reversed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order your list in descending order instead of ascending:

 Quick answer: `reversed="reversed"`.

Read below for explanation:

In previous versions of HTML, the only way to achieve this was to place a value attribute on each lielement, with successively decreasing values.

```
<h3>Top 5 TV Series</h3>
<ol>
  <li value="5">Friends
  <li value="4">24
  <li value="3">The Simpsons
  <li value="2">Stargate Atlantis
  <li value="1">Stargate SG-1
</ol>
```

The problem with that approach is that manually specifying each value can be time consuming to write and maintain, and the value attribute was not allowed in the HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0 Strict DOCTYPEs (although HTML 5 fixes that problem and allows the value attribute)
The new markup is very simple: just add a reversed attribute to the ol element, and optionally provide a start value. If there’s no start value provided, the browser will count the number of list items, and count down from that number to 1.

```
<h3>Greatest Movies Sagas of All Time</h3>
<ol reversed>
  <li>Police Academy (Series)
  <li>Harry Potter (Series)
  <li>Back to the Future (Trilogy)
  <li>Star Wars (Saga)
  <li>The Lord of the Rings (Trilogy)
</ol>
```

Since there are 5 list items in that list, the list will count down from 5 to 1.
The reversed attribute is a boolean attribute. In HTML, the value may be omitted, but in XHTML, it needs to be written as: reversed="reversed".

Source: https://dzone.com/articles/html-5-reverse-ordered-lists

Answer (score 1):

**Use this hope this help**
its supported in modern browsers

```
<ol reversed="reversed" start="3">
   <li> lorem ipsum </li>
   <li> Lorem ipsum dollar amet </li>
   <li> dollar amet </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

check this link out ...
you can use `flex-direction: row-reverse`;

[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flex-direction)