# Reverse the numbering order across multiple OL (not list order)

Tags: html, css, html-lists, reverse, css-counter

I'd like to use CSS to obtain an ordered list with continued numbering and in reverse. See attached figure.

[image]

Naturally, I'd like the resulting list to be in reverse order, i.e., [5], [4], etc.

Do I have to redesign the CSS part or is it a simple change? I can't figure out how to obtain the reverse numbering.

P.S.: I apologize for not putting the code in the question. Stack Overflow kept saying there was something wrong with it, even though everything was formed correctly in the preview. I lost patience after a few minutes trying to "fix" it.

Comment: make a fiddle maybe? the image upload resizes it enough to make it readable for ants :P

Comment: Its very tough to see but you would have to probably do this (1) When you reset the counter use `counter-reset: counter-name 6` and (2) When you increment the counter use `counter-increment: counter-name -1`. This would decrement the counter instead of the default increment. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ft412d9g/).

Comment: I noticed it's tough to see, but you can drag the image to your browser's tab bar and it'll display the image in the actual size. http://i.stack.imgur.com/2RJkD.png

Comment: Thanks! I'll create a Fiddle next time! :)

Harry, i see what you did. But it does require a manual intervention (the number 6 in the counter-reset). I'm wondering if there's a way to fully automate this, i.e., I just have to add li items to the HTML and not have to change the CSS code.

Comment: This may help with the reversing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695000/how-to-display-a-reverse-ordered-list-in-html

Comment: You can use something like `<ol start="yourStartNumber"></ol>` where "yourStartNumber" is written dynamically by either your javascript or backend code.

Comment: If there's really no way to fully automate this, then I'll settle for the manual approach with counter-reset and counter-increment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using CSS Counters

Currently there is no way to fully automate **reverse numbering across multiple** `ol` **elements** (without reversing the order of display of list items) with CSS counters when the no. of elements is dynamic. If reversing the order of display of list on the whole is fine, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695000/how-to-display-a-reverse-ordered-list-in-html).

You can make use of a bit of JavaScript along with counters to achieve this. The approach would be as follows:

- Using JS, get the count (`liCount`) of applicable `li` elements when the page is loaded.
- Set `liCount` as the second parameter for the `counter-reset` property on the parent container which would contain all the applicable `ol` elements. The second parameter to `counter-reset` property represents the initial/start value of the counter.
- In CSS, set `-1` as the second parameter for the `counter-increment` property. Generally the second parameter is the number by which the counter would be incremented every time. Here, since the value is set as `-1` the counter would actually get decremented.
- As normal, display the value of the counter using a `:before` pseudo element.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var liCount = document.querySelectorAll('ol > li').length;
  document.body.setAttribute('style', 'counter-reset: li ' + (liCount + 1));
}
```

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
}
ol > li {
  counter-increment: li -1;
}
ol > li:before {
  content: "[" counter(li) "]";
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h3>Year</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#2010-2015">2010-2015</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2007-2008">2007-2008</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h3 id="2010-2015">2010-2015</h3>
<ol>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>
<h3 id="2007-2008">2007-2008</h3>
<ol>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ol>
```

---

### Why not reversed attribute?

- Browser Support for [CSS counter](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters) is much better than the [reversed HTML5 attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol). The reversed attribute is not at all supported by IE and Opera.
- JS would still be required irrespective of the approach used (to assign `counter-reset` value for counters, `start` value for `ol reversed`) but the JS for setting `counter-reset` is much simpler than the other when the numbering is across multiple ordered lists.

Below is a sample snippet using the `reversed` attribute. **I take no credit for the approach** as it was taken from the linked thread and other answer here. I have **used it with added JS only to illustrate** what I meant in Point 2 above.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var liCount = document.querySelectorAll('ol > li').length;
  var olEls = document.querySelectorAll('ol[reversed]');

  var prevLiCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < olEls.length; i++) {
    /* the below lines are required because start for first ol is from 5 whereas for next is from 2 */
    olEls[i].setAttribute('start', liCount - prevLiCount);
    prevLiCount = olEls[i].querySelectorAll('li').length;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h3>Year</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#2010-2015">2010-2015</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2007-2008">2007-2008</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h3 id="2010-2015">2010-2015</h3>
<ol reversed="reversed">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ol>
<h3 id="2007-2008">2007-2008</h3>
<ol reversed="reversed">
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, Harry. I did find examples of using JavaScript and JQuery about this. I'm only interested in reverse numbering. And another important requirement is the ability to continue the reverse numbering in different ol elements. Your solution requires setting an id for the ol element, but what if I have multiple ol elements with continued reverse numbering? Example:

Part 1  
[5] A  
[4] B  

Part 2  
[3] C  

Part 3  
[2] D  
[1] E

Comment: @Bruno: I included an `id` and set the property on the OL only for example. You can directly set the property on the parent which will have all the OLs that are to be number (or body like in this case). Please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: this looks almost perfect! The problem now is that it's changing the counter for all li elements in the page. It should only change it for the ol elements. I think the problem is with the JavaScript part. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/nYRTK/71/

Comment: @Bruno That's pretty simple. We just need to modify the selectors. Please refer to my update in the answer.

Comment: Awesome! I've learned a lot from your solution! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Hi. I'm searching for something similar but I want the counter to reset for each ol. Is there a way to modify to code to achieve this?

Comment: @AMayer I think the best would be to ask a new question, not just a comment

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```html
<ol reversed start="5">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Reversed is a nice idea but it is not at all supported in IE as far as I am aware. Yet +1 for the idea :)

Comment: Thanks, IMI. I did see that thread you posted as comment, but it didn't quite solve my problem because in addition to reversing to the numbering, I also want to have it continued in different ol elements.