# Reversing a list with CSS? (The items, not the numbering.)

Tags: css

Is it possible to reverse a list using CSS? That is, **without** javascript.

This is the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Reversed List</title>
<style type="text/css">
ol.reverse li { /* what goes here? */ }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ol class="reverse">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

And this should be the result:

1. Third
2. Second
3. First

(When Googling it always came up about the numbering, and [How to display a reverse-ordered list in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695000/how-to-display-a-reverse-ordered-list-in-html) looked like it was about the numbering, too, even though I now see that the answers were not.)

Comment: Did you Google anything? Did you try Googling "ol reverse"?

Comment: Wow this is one of those things I would never use CSS for. mostly just because I would never assume it could. And it even has an answer, its actually the coolest CSS feature i have seen in a while, trumping css only 3d objects easily based on its simplicity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reverse using flexbox:

```css
.reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<ol class="reverse" reversed>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: And that's (beside JS) the only way AFAIK

Comment: even though this is brilliant it will show as 3, 2, 1

Comment: @GottZ than here the `reversed` attribute might help finally.

Comment: So basically http://stackoverflow.com/a/25695068/383904

Comment: For some reason the counters are 0 on Firefox :( And can't be fixed manually because `counter-increment` only sees tree order.