# how to reverse Bootstrap Collapse items?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left

I need To reverse Bootstrap Collapse Items 
I started  a rtl project with Bootstrap . and for sure the nav menu items will be reversed cause it will start from right to left .
How can I reverse It .

[image: reversed menu]

anyone can help ?

Comment: Put them in a different order in the HTML...

Comment: I want them as this order in the normal view but in collapse must be reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try reversing the order with CSS. So taking from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695025/1663001) and wrapping it in a media query so it only applies on the mobile size:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    ul.navbar-nav {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    ul.navbar-nav > li {
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
}
```

Here's a demo of it in action:
http://www.bootply.com/xcbdwWMzkL#

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool theme called "bootstrap-rtl" that allows you to use bootstrap normally while it takes care of all "rtl" issues. I started using it for all my rtl (arabic) websites it helps a lot and it's so easy to use. you have just to include it's css file after including bootstrap and that's it.
you can download it from the link below.

[bootstrap-rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl)