# How to do li ascending order and descending order using only HTML and CSS not Jquery?

Tags: html, css

How can i make this list item in reverse order with using css only

```
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you expand on that? Do you want to reverse a numeric list? Or do you want to sort it? Or what?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695000/how-to-display-a-reverse-ordered-list-in-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695000/how-to-display-a-reverse-ordered-list-in-html)

Comment: HTML and CSS are purely static UI presentation formats. They have nothing to do with ordering at all. If you purely have HTML and CSS, use "Ctrl+X" and "Ctrl+V" to order your HTML code?

Comment: @VipulNayee There are solutions but you have to more specific. Can you please provide some code and it will be great if you can provide a working example where you are trying that.

Answer (score 1):

@Vipul Nayee Please check following code.

```css
ul#top-to-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
ul#top-to-bottom > li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
li#a {
    background:blue;
}
li#b {
    background:red;
}
li#c {
    background:purple;
}
li#d {
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="top-to-bottom">
    <li id="a">List 1</li>
    <li id="b">List 2</li>
    <li id="c">List 3</li>
    <li id="d">List 4</li>
</ul>
```