# Descending ordered lists in pandoc markdown

Tags: html, css, html-lists, markdown, pandoc

In HTML, I can reverse the numbering of an ordered list by simply adding a `reversed` attribute:

```
<ol reversed>
 <li>This is numbered 2</li>
 <li>This is numbered 1</li>
</ol>
```

Is there a method for achieving something similar in pandoc markdown? What I would like to do is to write the list in the usual way, as follows,

```
2. This is numbered 2
1. This is numbered 1
```

and then add some annotation (either markdown or raw HTML) which achieves the effect of the HTML code above. (Just writing the pandoc markdown list as above produces the usual ascending ordering of labels).  I am only interested in having the labels appear in a descending order: I want the items themselves to appear in the same order as in the HTML/Markdown code.

The [appropriate section](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#ordered-lists) of the pandoc manual does not seem to suggest anything specific.

One of the things which I tried, and which does not work, is to attempt to use CSS for adding the reversed attribute, after wrapping the markdown list in a `div` using raw HTML:

```
<style>
div.rev-lists > ol {
  reversed;
}
</style>

<div class="rev-lists">

 2. This is numbered 2
 1. This is numbered 1

</div>
```

But the CSS code fails to add the `reversed` attribute to the `ol` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS should be along the lines of (adapted [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695025/214446)):

```
.rev-lists > ol {
  list-style-type:none;
  counter-reset:item 6;
}
.rev-lists > ol > li {
  counter-increment:item -1;
}
.rev-lists > ol > li:after {
  content: counter(item);
}
```

P.S. Instead of:

```
<div class="rev-lists">
2. This is numbered 2
1. This is numbered 1
</div>
```

since pandoc 2.0 you can also do:

```
::: rev-lists
2. This is numbered 2
1. This is numbered 1
:::
```