# Can Quarto render a descending ordered (markdown) list into revealjs?

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

Can Quarto produce a descending ordered (markdown) list rendered into revealjs?

I found this: [Descending ordered lists in pandoc markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344340/descending-ordered-lists-in-pandoc-markdown) and tried adding a bunch of different CSS bits like this:

````
---
title: "blah"
format:
    revealjs:
      theme: [default]
---

## test

```{r}
```

```{css}
.rev-lists > ol > li {
  counter-increment:item -1;
}

```

::: {.rev-lists}
2. This is numbered 2
1. This is numbered 1
:::
````

but I still ended up with a slide showing

```
2. This is numbered 2
3. This is numbered 1
```

The only workaround I could figure out was to display the content as:

```
2: This is numbered 2
1: This is numbered 1
```

and that looks like a bunch of colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some HMTL syntax with `ol reversed` to reverse the order of the markdown list like this:

```
---
title: "blah"
format:
    revealjs:
      theme: [default]
---

## test

<ol reversed>
  <li>This is numbered 1</li>
  <li>This is numbered 2</li>
</ol>
```

Output:

[image]