# Reverse Display of an ordered list

Tags: html, css

I'd like to reverse the *display order* (not display enumeration value) of an ordered list. (The list doesn't specifically have to be an ordered list, it can be unordered)

Here is an example:

```
<ol> Ordered list
    <li> Last item
    <li> Second-to-last item
    <li> Middle item
    <li> Second item
    <li> First item
</ol>
```

It displays like this:

```
1. Last item
2. Second-to-last item
3. Middle item
4. Second item
5. First item
```

Using `<ol reversed>` looks like this:

```
5. Last item
4. Second-to-last item
3. Middle item
2. Second item
1. First item
```

So the numbers are fine, but the order is still incorrect. Is there anyway to actually get First Item to be displayed first? The numbering doesn't matter to me, I could use `<ul>`, but I figured `<ol>` portrays what I'm going for better.

And no, I can't just move First Item to the top of the list :p My foreach loop doesn't work like that.

Edit: Please read the question, this is not a duplicate :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a reverse-ordered list in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695000/how-to-display-a-reverse-ordered-list-in-html)

Comment: It's not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flex box with `flex-direction:column-reverse` would do this for you:

```
ol { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Working [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ra8dsamr/)

Result:

```
5. First item
4. Second item
3. Middle item
2. Second-to-list item
1. Last item
```

Also, don't forget to close your `<li>` tags.

Answer (score -2):

Use `<ol reversed start=[your value]>`. It will work.

Please see the example here . [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ra8dsamr/1/)