# CSS - Appending li tag in ul with flex-direction: column-reverse not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I am building a chat app interface. The chat messages should start from bottom and then user can scroll to top to lazy load older chat. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695025/6699134) answer to reverse the UL. However the rotation seems more like a hack with scrollbar position switched to left and mouse wheel scrolling being reversed. So I decided to go with the good approach of flex element.

```html
<body>
  <ul style="display:flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; overflow:auto; position: relative; height: 100%; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <li> some chat message1 </li>
    <li> some chat message2 </li>
    <li> some chat message3 </li>
    <li> some chat message4 </li>

  </ul>
</body>
```

This works fine, app fetch chat from db and then append the li tags to ul tags:

```js
$(element).appendTo('ul')
```

The problem starts when the app lazy loads older chats at top of the ul and then the screen jumps up overlapping chat element with extra blank space at the bottom. [NOTE: prepend works fine when adding new chat at the bottom of the screen but I am trying to append older chat at top of the screen]

For simple demo, try this to understand how appending new li affects [tap on "add item" button 5-6 times to see the problem]:

```js
let counter = 0;

$('button').on('click', (e) => {
 counter++;
            const newItem = $(`
                <li>
                    <div style="height:10em; background: lightgray; margin:0.5em; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
                        ${counter}
                    </div>
                </li>
            `)
            newItem.appendTo('ul');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style"height:100%'">
  <ul style="display:flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; overflow:auto; height:100vh; position: relative;  margin:0; padding:0;"></ul>
    <button style="position:fixed; left:0; bottom:0;"> Add item           </button>
</body>
```

**Tested: Chrome v89.0.4389.90**

Comment: Pretty sure you've found a browser bug, it works fine in Firefox, but does what you describe in Chrome.

Comment: @CallumMorrisson yes, it works fine in Firefox but not with Chrome & Chromium Edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it works if you `innerHTML +=` on the container, but you hit a bug in Chrome if you use append. Likely has something to do with the browser re-render triggers:

```js
const buttonAppend = document.getElementById('add-button-append');
const buttonInner = document.getElementById('add-button-inner');
const container = document.getElementById('message-container');
let counter = 0;

buttonAppend.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    counter++;
    const newItem = document.createElement('li');
    newItem.innerHTML = `
        <div style="height:10em; background: lightgray; margin:0.5em; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
            ${counter}
        </div>`;
    container.append(newItem);
})

buttonInner.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    counter++;
    const newItem = `
        <li>
            <div style="height:10em; background: lightgray; margin:0.5em; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
                ${counter}
            </div>
        </li>`;
    container.innerHTML += newItem;
})
```

```html
<body style="height: 100%">
    <ul id="message-container" style="display:flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; overflow:auto; height:100vh; position: relative;  margin:0; padding:0;"></ul>
    <div style="position:fixed; left:0; bottom:0;">
        <button id="add-button-append" > Add item appendChild</button>
        <button id="add-button-inner" > Add item innerHTML +=</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Could probably hack your way around it, but sounds like a good opportunity for you to harass the chrome dev team.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I tested it in actual chat screen and it works absolutely fine. And where can I report about this bug to chrome dev team? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Good question, I have no idea. maybe new.crbug.com? I've never tried to report a google bug, generally just look for a more common solution.